# calling a route with specific ip address

Tags: c#, asp.net

For the project I'm working on, I need to directly call the IP address of a computer within our C# environment.  We are using asp.net / mvc 3 and the customer facing website has a controller that will expose an endpoint to hit from within the admin area of the site.  This controller action will then call another private internal ip address that actually does the ground work.  Basically there are two machines, one is customer facing, and the other machine is more for setup.

```
<private_ip_address>/admin/do_something_private
```

Does C# have a direct way to call an IP address like this?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're doing? What does routing have to do with it?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I guess you are right and maybe routing isn't the right word.  But the way I was thinking (I am new to web btw), is that there is a controller route that is exposed to the admin site that a button press could activate to "do_something_fun."

Comment: what kind of service/app is at the remote ip site? if it's a web app, u use WebRequest, if it's somekind of exe, it may not work.

Comment: @Kelmen Yes it is a webapp.  Will modify my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the PCs can see each other you can always establish a communication between them via HTTP. Just make sure you know how the endpoint is configured and what kind of "requests" it understands. Yet, the client must be aware of any security implementation on the server side in order to successfully authenticate the request. That's as abstract as I can get provided that your question is way too abstract

Answer (score 0):

Your internal machine will have an external IP address. You'll need to point your external
L website to the external IP address of your modem/router and use your modem/router to route the request to the internal IP address. You can also put your internal machine on your router's DMZ but that's usually a bad idea.